Should survey results merge JetBrains products into one category?
I recently reviewed the latest survey results and observed the following: Visual Studio Code holds a 73.6% usage rate, Visual Studio 29.3%, and IntelliJ IDEA 26.8%.
Upon closer examination, I realised that JetBrains sub-products are listed in separate categories: PyCharm at 15.1%, WebStorm at 7.5%, PhpStorm at 5.9%, and so forth.
I believe these results present a skewed perspective because Visual Studio Code is used across all programming languages without differentiation in its usage. As someone who's used WebStorm some years, I can say that if I needed to work with PHP as an example, I would use PhpStorm. This is based on having a consistent experience across other JetBrains products (IDEA, CLion, and PyCharm, specifically). They share the same keybindings, workflows, git integration, plugins, built-in tools, etc. They are all the same product, separated only by licensing.
When aggregating all (visible) JetBrains products from the survey (excluding Android Studio, because that's cheating), the results are as follows:

JetBrains: 76.8%
Visual Studio Code: 73.6%
Visual Studio: 29.3%

(A developer can use more than one tool, this isn't meant to add up to 100%)
This aggregated data is more valuable to me as it reflects others' preferences for workflows similar to mine versus those favoring the VSCode workflow. However, this in and of itself now unfairly skews the results in favor of JetBrains because I can't know how many participants used multiple JetBrains products at once (I suspect it's a small number, but that's obviously subjective).
Should we consider merging all JetBrains products into a single category?

Still can't believe they left out Brief.

To be clear: Do the survey results aggregate all JetBrains products at any point, or is this something you did yourself?

@MisterMiyagi I don't know if there's a view in the survey that aggregate all product results. I manually counted up what is visible in the provided link, hence the "When aggregating all (visible) JetBrains products" part. It would be quite nice if such a view already exists.

"I believe these results present a skewed perspective because Visual Studio Code is used across all programming languages without differentiation in its usage." the survey also lists JetBrains Fleet, which is analogous to VS Code.

@AndrewT. Jetbrains Fleet is still in beta. So, while it might hold some value in the future, it doesn't mean much right now (and in fact, I recently tried it, it has a long still to go before it can match other JetBrains products).

I'm surprised how many people find value in VS Code, and it's long past beta. That said, I've only used it for C++. Maybe it shines for other languages.

@user4581301 I've enacted a policy at my company that, if you choose VS Code, you have three months to get to WebStorm's level of professionalism before the company will force a license down your throat. While I've seen experts online claim fantastic VS Code setups, the juniors simply can't manage this. We've only had three juniors, but the pattern was the same: They struggle with basics like var-level spell checkers, contextual auto-complete, and consistent tabbing. Basic git ops would take 30+ seconds. JetBrains is corporate OOTB. VS Code is tabula rasa and requires expert-level setup.

I think the JetBrains' IDEs should be kept separate because if you're looking for language specific IDEs (to meaningfully compare them by language) you'll want to look at a separate list and not at the aggregate.
VSCode's high adoption must be understood for what it is: a language agnostic tool. Although it's originally Microsoft it works with different languages due to community contributed plugins. That's not the JetBrains case for the most part, although I use some plugins I'm looking for a paid or free product (depending on my exact needs) that works out of the box with a complete feature set and is focused on a specific language.

in that case i would like to see which % of coders in language x use vs code to code so we can compare if vs code is used more for certain languages or jetbrains as it stands we can't really compare the tools because they are measured on different use cases

JetBrains is a company, IntelliJ is their flagship IDE. Both Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are (in origin) Microsoft products. This aggregation pretty much compares apples and oranges, in my opinion.
Even if you would relabel JetBrains to IntelliJ, where the fruits get actually mixed is in the existence of Visual Studio Code in that list, it doesn't belong. There is more in this world than text editors and IDEs, there is a middle ground where tools such as Visual Studio Code, Zed, NeoVIM and Emacs live and thrive. Not plain text editors, but not quite IDEs either - by design.

related to the "IDE" classification: Does VS Code count as an IDE? (absolutely shameless plug- especially my response)

If the reason is just to have this "obvious comparison", it could be nice, but people can calculate it themselves. As you've shown, anyone can easily do a naive sum of the numbers themselves if they so choose. An even harder no if you're proposing actually hard-merging the categories since that would be a lossy lowering of category resolution.

because I can't know how many participants used multiple JetBrains products at once

You can do a sum that counts unique responders to account for responders once the CSV is released here. And if people want, they can probably get an estimate on what technologies people edit sources for in VS Code by joining with the technologies used columns.
